# How can you create an in memory ModelContainer for SwiftData?

Tags: ios, swift, cloudkit, swift-data

## Background

I've been trying to learn SwiftData with iCloud syncing and want to create an in memory data store so I can test concepts with dummy data that's added on load and never saved.

That way I can play with the data shut down the app and re-load it to get back to the start. If I want to then play with existing data I can remove the memory only flag and use the synced iCloud data.

## Reason for question

The issue is that it seems to ignore `isStoredInMemoryOnly` when creating the SwiftData `ModelConfiguration` and saves to and loads from the iCloud source not the in memory one.

While I know I can quickly create a "delete and reset all" button I now want to know what I'm doing wrong as I also use this same flag for previewing so don't want other issues to occur due to testing in previews getting saved into my data storage.

## Assumptions

I read on none Apple sources that the parameter `isStoredInMemoryOnly` does what it says and stops the ModelContainer from storing the data in iCloud. I've found no official descriptions of this parameter but feel the name is clear.

## More info and re-creation

My first test *(using the below code)* worked fine as every time I closed the app it would lose the data but then I loaded the app in another simulator and found it saved the data to the iCloud as reloading the app didn't clear the data and nether did deleting and re-installing the app as it just pulled the previously saved data from iCloud...

I've tried it on a physical iPhone as well as deleting the app from all simulators and physical devices, deleting the iCloud data for that account as well as resetting the app from the CloudKit Console and now all tests are causing it to store all data in iCloud and I can't even replicate the original sucess.

Here is some example code (basically the Apple default iCloud sync code but with `isStoredInMemoryOnly` set to `true`.

## Questions

1. I guess the first thing to ask is if anyone can confirm (via Apple docs) if the `isStoredInMemoryOnly` param when creating a new `ModelConfiguration` (shown on line 20 below) is in fact meant to prevent it storing to the CloudKit Container or if that's just a bad name and everyone saying so has assumed.
2. If that's true is there something wrong with my example code or is it just a (known?) bug.

## Example code

Below is a quick example. To use it you'll need an empty iCloud container connected with the `CloudKit` Service selected.

```
import SwiftUI
import SwiftData
import Foundation

@Model
final class Item {
    var timestamp: Date?
    
    init(timestamp: Date) {
        self.timestamp = timestamp
    }
}

@main
struct CloudKitTest_TempApp: App {
    var sharedModelContainer: ModelContainer = {
        let schema = Schema([
            Item.self,
        ])
        let modelConfiguration = ModelConfiguration(schema: schema, isStoredInMemoryOnly: true)

        do {
            return try ModelContainer(for: schema, configurations: [modelConfiguration])
        } catch {
            fatalError("Could not create ModelContainer: \(error)")
        }
    }()

    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
        }
        .modelContainer(sharedModelContainer)
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @Environment(\.modelContext) private var modelContext
    @Query private var items: [Item]
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationSplitView {
            List {
                ForEach(items) { item in
                    if (item.timestamp != nil) {
                        NavigationLink {
                            Text("Item at \(item.timestamp!, format: Date.FormatStyle(date: .numeric, time: .standard))")
                        } label: {
                            Text(item.timestamp!, format: Date.FormatStyle(date: .numeric, time: .standard))
                        }
                    }
                }
                .onDelete(perform: deleteItems)
            }
            .toolbar {
                ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarTrailing) {
                    EditButton()
                }
                ToolbarItem {
                    Button(action: addItem) {
                        Label("Add Item", systemImage: "plus")
                    }
                }
            }
        } detail: {
            Text("Select an item")
        }
    }
    
    private func addItem() {
        withAnimation {
            let newItem = Item(timestamp: Date())
            modelContext.insert(newItem)
        }
    }
    
    private func deleteItems(offsets: IndexSet) {
        withAnimation {
            for index in offsets {
                modelContext.delete(items[index])
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I wonder right now, why the sample data is mixed into my regular data after doing some Preview debugging, always using `isStoredInMemoryOnly: true`. I fear the answer is no.